# Unity C# code works for around 10 seconds and then stops

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

What's wrong with this code?

CurrentGunImage is an image of the gun the code is a component of and GunImage 1-5 are pictures of each other gun in the game. I have the same code on each gun in the game.

The intention is that when the player equips a particular gun then a sprite of it is shown on screen and when they choose a different gun any other sprite is deactivated and the new one is activated.

The script works initially (for between 10 and 40 seconds usually) but then the image stops with no new images being shown and the image it stops working on never being removed. Sometimes after a few seconds it starts working again but always stops not long after and doesn't start working again.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class GunUIImage : MonoBehaviour {


    public GameObject CurrentGunImage;
    public GameObject GunImage1;
    public GameObject GunImage2;
    public GameObject GunImage3;
    public GameObject GunImage4;
    public GameObject GunImage5;

    void Start () {

        CurrentGunImage.SetActive (true);
        GunImage1.SetActive (false);
        GunImage2.SetActive (false);
        GunImage3.SetActive (false);
        GunImage4.SetActive (false);
        GunImage5.SetActive (false);

    }

}
```

Thank you for any help or for any information on a better way to do this.

Comment: With the code you posted, we can't do absolutely nothing. Your code does nothing at all, maybe you didn't copy-pasted everything?

Comment: I removed:

using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class GunUIImage : MonoBehaviour {

but I've edited them back in. This is the entirety of the code, it just activates and deactivates a few game objects.

Comment: That is not enough code to even guess at why your problem is what it is.

Answer (score 3):

Problem solved. The code was only activating the first time (or first few times) for each weapon. I moved the code from Void Start into void Update and its all good working fine